# How Do I Do Cool Dialog Stuff (MFC)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Whether I have to use a dialog box or a message doesn't really matter but I need to somehow do the following:

I've got a dialog-based MFC application. The main dialog calls a procedure that creates a thread. The call to the procedure is inside while loop. (Basically it's a file processing program - spawning off a thread for doing the file saving. So, a thread is spawned for each file that is being saved.)

I am suspending and resuming the main thread properly. However, I don't know how to get a message box/dialog box to display saying something like "please wait" and still have the main dialog update... 0.o

Basically, I want to lock the main dialog from user interaction (like keeping them from selecting anything or clicking any buttons), but I want the progress bar on the dialog to update...

Any ideas?

Comment: a bit old but does the work: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0297/wicked/wicked0297.aspx

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for! thank you! would you mind making that an answer so I can give you credit for it? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit old but does the work:
 [microsoft.com/msj/0297/wicked/wicked0297.aspx](http://microsoft.com/msj/0297/wicked/wicked0297.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is very old app.

You do not need to follow this sample; however you can follow the idea.

You have two choices: 
Create progress bar in the main dialog, disable all dialog but progress. Start thread passing dialog’s handle. From the thread use this handle to send a custom message to allow dialog advancing progress. 
Another message would notify dialog that thread is done and enable all controls.

Another choice would be to spawn modeless dialog, start the thread passing modeless dialog’s handle and process as described above.
Pass main dialog pointer to the modeless dialog to be used to disable and enable main dialog upon modeless start (OnInitDialog) and enable upon receiving thread complete message, before destroying modeless dialog window.